# Как в 1С 8.3 установить табличную часть документа на его форме

Tags: 1с, форма, таблицы

У меня вопрос следующего характера. В 1с 8.3 Мне нужно сделать следующее. У меня есть документ "Занятие" (в детском саду). В нём раньше был реквизит "Сотрудник". Но бизнес-правила изменились. Мне необходимо ввести реквизит "СписокСотрудников" по данному занятию. Я сделал это введением нового элемента табличной части "СписокСотрудников", в которой только один реквизит "Сотрудник". То есть несколько сотрудников по данному документу "Занятие" можно отобразить в этой табличной части. Правильно это или нет - я не знаю.
  Так вот я в 1с 8.3 - чайник. Давно в нём программировал. У меня вопрос: как на форме "ГрупповоеЗанятие" в общем смысле отобразить таблицу с несколькими Сотрудниками, а не одним, по данному групповому занятию? Я пробовал делать так: ввёл реквизит формы типа "СписокЗначений" и указал Источник Данных "Справочник.Ссылка.Сотрудники". А на форме поместил элемент "Таблица" "СписокСотрудников" со ссылкой на этот реквизит формы (СписокЗначений). Конечно, при нажатии на "Сохранить" ничего там не сохраняется. Как это всё связать с табличной частью документа "СписокСотрудников"? И как вообще решить данную проблему? Мне бы ответы более подробные т.к. я - чайник в 1с 8.3 Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Answer (score 1):

В конфигураторе, в конструкторе формы документа "занятие", в окне справа вверху разверните сущность "Объект" и перетащите реквизит "СписокСотрудников" на саму форму, куда нужно.

Можно сохранять данные и в реквизите формы, установив параметру "Сохранение данных" значение "Использовать" (в свойствах формы), но в данном случае это нецелесообразно

На скриншоте стрелочкой указано место где будет реквизит (в дереве объекта), оттуда и нужно перетащить его на форму

[image: я отметил место где будет реквизит]